# How to make recaptcha work with verification

Tags: php, recaptcha

I tried this in my code and I entered the right secret key just didn't want to put it out there but everytime I submit my form even with it checked it shows up with the error that it isn't filled out, without the captacha stuff in the form it works just fine. Can someone please help me fix this issue I would like it to make sure you filled it out before it sends it to my email!!

```
<h2 class="text-center" id="whatwedo">Contact form</h2><hr class="titlehr"></div></div><br>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
           $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

        $from = $fullname; 
        $to = 'mcgarrywebdesign@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Contact Form';

        $body = "From: $fullname\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Subject: $subject\n description: $description";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['fullname']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['phone']) {
            $errPhone = 'Please enter your phone number';
        }
        if (!$_POST['subject']) {
            $errSubject = 'Please enter the subject';
        }
        if (!$_POST['description']) {
            $errDescription = 'Please enter the description';
        }



        if(!$captcha){
          $errcaptcha = "Please check the the captcha form";

        }


        // If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errPhone && !$errSubject && !$errDescription && !$errcaptcha) {
      $secretKey = "secret key";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          $result =  "You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out";
        } else {



    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }}
?>
<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$result</p>";?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6"> <form action="contact.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname">
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
   <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone">
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPhone</p>";?>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">  
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errSubject</p>";?>
  </div>
       <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errDescription</p>";?>
  </div>

 <br>

            </div></div>


            <div class="g-recaptcha text-center mx-auto d-block" data-sitekey="6LdhyXcUAAAAANrj8qTSLKcrbjVX6ij07Dqw0awe"></div>
<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errcaptcha</p>";?>


        <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto d-block" style="width: 190px !important;height: 60px !important;font-size: 25px;">Submit</button></div></div></form>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$captcha` is never defined.

Comment: I forgot to put that code on there, now it is up @IdontDownVote